# Bean not found exception, caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

Creating a Rest API application on spring Boot: 3.1.0 and JDK 17.

After adding **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** dependency in pom.xml, started getting the below error. Irrespective of whatever dependency i add or remove(after adding spring-boot-starter-data-jpa), it's always giving **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext** exception.

Log:

```
ringframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed
19-06-2023 18:04:49.834 [main]
                ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:261)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:787)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:592)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294)
        at com.sunday.locateyourplace.locateyourplaceapp.LocateYourPlaceApplication.main(LocateYourPlaceApplication.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/persistence/PersistenceContext
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:425)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:416)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findInjectionMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:370)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1083)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceContext
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sunday.locateyourplace</groupId>
    <artifactId>locate-your-place-svc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>locate-your-place-service</name>
    <description>locate your place service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <io.swagger.version>1.6.2</io.swagger.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${io.swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In the application.properties file i have added configuration for postgresql db connectivity.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
#spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.auto_quote_keyword=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/locateyourplace
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=*******
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Repository file:

```
@Repository
public interface UserAuthenticationRepository extends CrudRepository<UserDetails, String> {

}
```

Comment: Remove the version from `spring-boot-starter-web`. remove `spring-data-jpa` and the jakarta dependencies (also from validation), remove version from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`. In short your dependencies are a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your dependencies, you are trying to much and are mixing jars from different version of Spring Boot.

Assuming you are using `spring-boot-starter-parent` as your parent with the proper version.

1. Remove the version tags from the `spring-boot-starter-*` dependencies
2. Remove the `jakarta.persistence` / `jakarta.validation` dependencies
3. `spring-security-crypto` is from an incompatible version as well
4. remove `spring-data-jpa`
5. Apparently you want validation add `spring-boot-starter-validation`.
6. Remove `spring-web` dependency, already part of the `spring-boot-starter-web`.

```xml
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
     <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
      <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${io.swagger.version}</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.12.0</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Free bonus:** Remove the `@Repository` from your repository interface, it doesn't add anything but clutter. Spring Data has other means of detecting the repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the input M. Denium, after doing the suggested things i am getting error 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver.

To get rid of this i added dependency 

<dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>42.5.2</version>
                </dependency>

Comment: then different error occurred which is 

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.sunday.locateyourplace.dal.client.UserAuthenticationClientImpl required a bean of type 'com.sunday.locateyourplace.dal.sql.repository.UserAuthenticationRepository' that could not be found.

Comment: BTW, there is no parent pom, that's why i have added version for all the dependencies.

Comment: You should add the parent pom, as that is the source of your problems, you are throwing together random versions of dependencies which aren't designed to work together. Hence the parent pom in a spring boot project, or if you must at least the dependencies pom in your `dependencyManagement` section.

Comment: But even in parent pom, i will have to give dependency versions myself, isn't it? Or is there a way to get the compatible versions in pom.xml?

Comment: If you specify the version you don't need to specify the versions. You only need to add the `spring-boot-starter-parent` with the version you want `3.1.0` and that is it, everything else will be provided for managed dependencies.

Comment: After correcting the dependencies, getting error 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory

Comment: So you haven't corrected your dependencies, as that is for older spring boot versions. As stated you are just throwing stuff together and hope it works. Properly define the parent (see the modified answer) and let Spring Boot manage the versions.

Comment: Please check my modified pom, i believe all the dependencies are correct now.
 Getting error: 
**Parameter 0 of constructor in com.sunday.locateyourplace.dal.client.UserAuthenticationClientImpl required a bean of type 'com.sunday.locateyourplace.dal.sql.repository.UserAuthenticationRepository' that could not be found.**

Comment: Please don't provide (partial stacktraces) as comments as those are unreadable. Your original question has been answered, you are now running into another issue. Which I suspect is due to using some other library (or your code) that actually isn't compatible with JakartaEE but is for JavaEE and hence you would need to migrate that code (which is another question).